# Is File Stream really supposed to replace Google Drive (Backup and Sync Google)?

Tags: google-drive, synchronization

Does Google really intend to replace Google Drive (Backup and Sync Google) with File Stream, as I have read?  (For example https://techcrunch.com/2017/09/07/google-launches-drive-file-stream-to-replace-the-google-drive-desktop-app-for-g-suite-users/)

If so, do I need to pay (and how much)?  What is my deadline?  When is it recommended to make the switch, i.e. when will the kinks have been ironed out?

Comment: Google Drive is not the same as "Google Drive desktop app"

Answer (score 1):

> Update (March 22, 2018): This post has been updated to reflect that Google Drive for Mac/PC will now stop working on May 12, 2018
>
> Drive File Stream is a new desktop application that allows you to quickly access all of your Google Drive files on demand, directly from your computer, meaning you use almost none of your hard drive space and spend less time waiting for files to sync.
>
> Support for Google Drive for Mac/PC ending on December 11th, 2017; Google Drive for Mac/PC to stop working on May 12, 2018
>
> **https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2017/09/drive-file-stream-from-google.html**

Comment: But on my computers, Backup and Sync is still working.